# Passing in array to a function

Tags: c

```
int main(){

    int right[2][3] = {
    {1,4,6}, {2,7,5}
    }

    ....


    calc(right);
}

int calc(int ** right){
    printf("%i", right[0][0]);
}
```

I calc function that calculate some numbers based on a matrix, but I dont' know why i get seg fault when I access the variable right within the calc function.  does any body know the solution?

edit:
right now that is all it's doing at calc function.  I have some calc stuff but it's all commented out trying to figure out how to access this variable.

Comment: You need to post the code for `calc` function for any body to help.

Comment: You probably try to access the whole array but you only initialize right[0] and [1] IMO.

Comment: can you paste the code of calc as well?and why are you using int ** right??

Comment: possible duplicate of *many* questions, including [Passing arrays and matrices to functions as pointers and pointers to pointers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546860/passing-arrays-and-matrices-to-functions-as-pointers-and-pointers-to-pointers-in)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two-dimensional arrays in C don't work the way you think they do. (Don't worry, you're not alone -- this is a common misconception.)

The assumption implicit in the code is that `right` is an array of `int *` pointers, each of which points to an array of `int`. It *could* be done this way -- and, confusingly, the syntax for accessing such an array would be the same, which is probably what causes this misconception.

What C *actually* does is to make `right` an array of 12 `int`s, layed out contiguously in memory. An array access like this

```
a=right[i][j];
```

is effectively equivalent to this:

```
int *right_one_dimensional=(int *)right;
a=right[i*3 + j];
```

To pass your array to the `calc` function, you need to do this:

```
int calc(int *right, size_t d){
    // For example
    a=right[i*d + j];
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
int right[2][3] = {
    {1,4,6}, {2,7,5}
};

calc(&right[0][0], 3);
```

Edit: For more background on this, the question linked to in Binary Worrier's comment is definitely worth looking at.

Comment: You could also specify calc as `int calc(int right[][3])` and call it by simple doing `calc(right);`

Answer (score 2):

Although a one-dimensional array is automatically converted to a pointer, the same does not hold for a multi-dimensional array and multi-level pointers.

If you change the order of the `calc` and `main` functions (or if you provide a prototype for `calc` before `main`), you will get a complaint from the compiler that it can convert `right` to the type `int**`.

The reason is that `right` is declared as an "array of 4 arrays of 3 `int`". This can be automatically converted to "pointer to array of 3 `int`" (`int (*)[3]`), but that is where the conversions stop.
`calc` on the other hand expects a "pointer to a pointer to `int`", which is a completely different beast from a "pointer to array of 3 `int`".

There are two possible solutions:

1. Change `calc` to accept a pointer to an array (or array of arrays):

```
   int calc(int right[][3])
```

2. Change `right` to be a pointer to a pointer:

```
    int temp_array[4][3];
    int* temp_array2[4] = { temp_array[0], temp_array[1], temp_array[2], temp_array[3] };
    int** right = temp_array2;
```