# Why does 2 dimension array passing to function requires its size?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Inspired [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function) quiestion .

Why does  -

```
void display(int p[][SIZE]) // allowed
```

and

```
void display(int p[][]) // not allowed
```

?

Comment: Because an array is not a pointer, and an array of arrays is not a pointer-to-pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because arrays *decay* to pointers when passed to a function. If you do not provide the cardinality of the second dimension of the array, the compiler would not know how to dereference this pointer.

Here is a longer explanation: when you write this

```
p[index]
```

the compiler performs some pointer arithmetic to find the address of the element that it needs to reference: it multiplies `index` by the size of `p`'s element, and adds it to the base address of `p`:

```
address = <base address of p> + index * <size of p's element>
```

When you try passing an array like this, `p[][]`, the compiler knows only the base address of `p`, but not the size of its element. It is in order for the compiler to know the size of `p`'s element that you need to provide the cardinality of the second dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Because a 2D array is stored row wise and hence the function needs the number of columns so that it knows when the next row begins.

Answer (score 2):

That's because caculations in pointers requires that.
When p points to 2 dimentional array that's size is `SIZE` this operation `p+=3` is calculated this way:

if the value of p is a constant equal ADRESS
p receive this value ADRESS + 3*SIZE.

That's because arithmitic in pointers is different from arithmitic in real numbers. This calculation can't be done without knowing the size of the array.