# difference between *argv[] and argv[][]

Tags: arrays, c, argv

why I this peace of compiles without error :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[][]){

        return 0;
}
```

I know `char **argv` and `char *argv[]` are the same,but  what's difference between `char *argv[]` and `char argv[][]`?

I think my question is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213580/difference-between-char-argv-and-char-argv-for-the-second-argument-to-main) question, it's about difference between `*argv[]` and `**argv`.

Comment: I don't think the linked duplicate actually answers what's being asked here. But there is [a duplicate that explains it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20523665/10077).

Comment: The question I linked is a different question than the one that was given as a duplicate. I believe that it should be added to, or replace, the link given in the duplicate closure. I can't do that because I don't have a C gold badge.