# C++ error in 2 dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I am encountering some memory issues while working with a 2 dimensional array in c++.

Excerpt from main:

```
int **A,**B,**C;    
A = new int*[d];
B = new int*[d];
C = new int*[d];

if (file.is_open()){
  for (int i = 0; i < d ;i++){
    A[i] = new int[d];
    C[i] = new int[d];
    for(int j = 0; j < d ;j++){
      if(getline(file,line)){
        A[i][j] = atoi(line.c_str());
      }else{
        cout<<"Dimension does not match inputfile.\n";
        return(1);
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < d ;i++){
    B[i] = new int[d];
    for(int j = 0; j < d ;j++){
      if(getline(file,line)){
        B[i][j] = atoi(line.c_str());
      }else{
        cout<<"Dimension does not match inputfile.\n";
        return(1);
      }
    }
  }
  file.close();
}
...
cout<<"A4\n";
PrintM(A,n);
AddMatrix(B,bi,bj,B,bi,bj+n/2,C,ci,cj,n/2);
cout<<"A5\n";
PrintM(A,n);
...
```

The add matrix routine:

```
void AddMatrix(int** X,int ai,int aj,int** Y, int bi,int bj,int** Z,int ci,int cj,int n){
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++) 
      Z[i+ci][j+cj] = X[i+ai][j+aj] + Y[i+bi][j+bj];
}
```

The PrintM routine:

```
void PrintM(int **P,int n){
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
      cout<<"[";
      for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if (j != n-1)
          cout<<P[i][j]<<",";
        else
          cout<<P[i][j]<<"]\n";
      }
  }
  cout<<endl;
}
```

And the output:

```
A4
[0,0]
[0,0]

A5
[4,0]
[0,0]
```

I have no idea why the array A is being modified in the AddMatrix routine, as I'm not even using it in the call to the routine.  I haven't included all the code here (300 lines long), but I couldn't recreate the problem in a short example.  I'm not doing anything silly like saying A = C anywhere.  I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: put a data breakpoint on the single value that you know has changed and should not. also, use valgrind

Comment: You problem is probably in the code you didn't include. How are `A` and `B` initialized?

Comment: this AddMatrix(B,bi,bj,B,bi,bj+n/2,C,ci,cj,n/2); is for matrix A5 i think. What you are passing for matrix A4??

Comment: I agree with @agbinfo. Offhand, it looks like a buffer overrun may be the culprit.

Comment: You have omitted the definition of B and C. Without that information, any answers here are as authoritative as the press giving causes for the Malaysian Airplane Disaster. This is one possible cause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Buffer overflow in writing**

As the function is modifying other data not passed to the function, this looks like a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) in writing. The only write in the function is in the line

```
Z[i+ci][j+cj] = X[i+ai][j+aj] + Y[i+bi][j+bj];
```

You are writing outside `Z`, in the memory allocated/destined for `A`. You want to write inside `Z`, i.e. you must check that

- `0<=i+ci<DZ1`, with `DZ1` of the 1st dimension of `Z`
- `0<=j+cj<DZ2`, with `DZ2` of the 2nd dimension of `Z`

Now, both `i` and `j` are run in a loop and have minimum `0` and maximum value `n-1`. The `2` inequalities must be respected for every value of `i` and `j`, so we obtain

- `0<=ci<DZ1-(n-1)`, with `DZ1` of the 1st dimension of `Z`
- `0<=cj<DZ2-(n-1)`, with `DZ2` of the 2nd dimension of `Z`

If the sizes `DZ1` and `DZ2` are known, consider adding an `assert` at the beginning of `AddMatrix()`, like

```
assert(0<=ci<DZ1-(n-1) && "buffer overrun in the 1st dimension");
assert(0<=cj<DZ2-(n-1) && "buffer overrun in the 2nd dimension");
```

and add  `#include<cassert>` at the top. The above will solve the problem you have with `A` changing in a call where `A` was not even passed as argument. This was a buffer overflow in **writing** in `Z`.

However, you may also have a buffer overflow in **reading** from `X` and `Y`. This would not affect `A`, and you would realize you have a bug possibly much later in the development.

If you plan on using this code for long time or in a large project, add more asserts checking the bounds of `ai`,`aj`,`bi`,`bj`.

**Buffer overflow in reading**

The other possibility is that the object `A` is smaller then `n` by `n`, and when you print `A` you are actually printing part of `C`. Check that `n` is the size of `A`.

Comment: I've edited the code to show how the arrays were initialized.  I did a print line check to make sure that i+ci <DZ1 and j+cj<DZ2.  In the omitted code n = d/2, so I can't see how it would be reading/writing information that is outside of the bounds of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers everyone, I found the problem in a different part of the code. I was recursively calling a function where A and C were the same object.  *****Slaps self on wrist*****

Comment: LOL... that happens.
So - just to let you know - this question now probably won't help anybody else if they have a similar issue. What generally happens now is that we vote to close it. So don't take it personal when that happens - it's just to make sure that questions will answers are what stick around in the S/O community. :)

Comment: Taryn, I would vote to close this question too. No offense taken.

Comment: @MattPennington, I don't see how this can explain the error presented above. Good that you somehow sorted it out anyway.