# Inserting a matrix and an integer to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, matrix

Lets say I have a matrix with x rows and y columns and an integer `a` and I want to make a function that takes the matrix and multiply ever row with the integer a ( I know I can do this simply with a for loop ). How do I write the beginning of the function ? `function( int a, matrix[x],[y])`? (I'm using `C`)

Comment: What language are you using? Without that detail, your question is too broad.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say I'm using C .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function check out this question

Answer (score 1):

Creating a matrix (2D array) in C isn't as simple as in C#, Java etc. You have to create an *array of arrays* - by using pointers. Let me show you a function:

Function fill2D() is taking 3 arguments - pointer to matrix, number of rows, number of columns.

The **declaration** of a fill2D() function in functions.h file:

```
extern void fill2D(float **pole, int r, int c);`
```

The **definition** of a fill2D() function in functions.c file:

```
void fill2D(float **pole, int r, int c) {
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        pole[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

And here's a code in **main.c**:

```
fill2D(p_float_array, rows, columns);
```

Definition of arguments for fill2D() function:

```
float **p_float_array = NULL;
int rows = 10;
int columns = 3;
```

Hope, it's a helpful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the simplest way. You can declare the 2d array in multiple ways.

```
void ApplyConstant(int c, int matrix[][col], int row)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        // access by matrix[row][j]
    }
}
```

Comment: I said I know how to do it in a loop . I just wanted to know how to insert them to a function

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, you need the declaration of this function.
In this case i use:

```
void func(int a, int* matrix, int len);
int main(void) {
    int matrix[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
    func(3,matrix[4],4);
    return 0;
}

void func(int a, int* matrix, int len) {
    //your loop code here...
}
```

Hope it's helped you .