# Matrix, pointers, C*

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I have code like this:

```
void print_matrix(int **a, int n) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d\t", *(a+i*n+j));
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main () {
  int matrix[3][3];

  insert (matrix); /* Function that reads Matrix from stdin */
  print_matrix(matrix, 3);
  return 1; 
}
```

I receive GCC error:

> expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[3]

I read all related topics but I still couldn't find answer to my question, so before you mark it as duplicate please read it.

Pointers are not Arrays, I understand that. I've read somewhere that elements are not sequential, in that case, this could happen: 111 222 333 -> 111 is address of first int array, 222 is address of second int array, and 333 is address of third int array. But if this is the case, I don't understand why GCC gives me an error.

First I would like someone to confirm me that what I've read is true. Then I would really appreciate if someone could give me answer.

Note that I understand that `*(a+i*n+j)` is incorrect in case that memory for matrix is not sequential.

Best regards.

Comment: The types are not equivalent, `int [3][3]` is contigous storage of 9 integers, while `int **` is a pointer to (*possibly an array of pointers*) pointer.

Comment: Can you tell me what could be possible fixes?

Comment: But you are dereferncing wrong, can you write `a[j][i]`?

Comment: I understand why it won't work now, but I don't know what could be possible fixes besides print_matrix(int a[][3], int n).

Comment: `print_matrix(int *a, int n)`

Comment: And while we're at the topic, why you have to say a[][3], and not a[][] as function argument?

Comment: @Ilya GCC: int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[3]

Comment: Well, you can cast to a pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way of passing 2 dimensional array into a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass `int[3][3]`, the function receives a pointer to the `(int*)[3]` which is a **pointer to an array of 3 int's**. Because an array gets converted into a pointer to its first element when you pass it to a function.

So adjust the function accordingly. One way is to receive it as a pointer to an array. You array indexing is wrong too. You can index just like how you would index a real the array.

```
void print_matrix(int (*a)[3], int n) {

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

}
```

If you use C99, you can pass both dimensions:

```
void print_matrix(int x, int y, int a[x][y]) {

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < y; j++)
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

}
```

and call it as:

```
  print_matrix(3, 3, matrix);
```

---

Just to illustrate how you would access the individual "arrays":

```
void print_matrix(int (*a)[3], int n) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       int *p = a+i;
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%d\t", p[j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

}
```

Comment: When you pass int[3][3], the function receives a pointer to the (int*)[3] which is a pointer to an array of 3 int's. Because an array gets converted into a pointer to its first element when you pass it to a function. - Can you explain this a little bit more?

Comment: In C, you can neither pass nor return an *array* to/from a function. It always gets converted into a pointer to its first element. So the array loses its size information and becomes just a pointer (inside a function) which is also the reason why you can't use `sizeof` on it to get its actual size. See [What is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) which specifically covers this topic.

Comment: So basically when I pass to function int[3][3] ONLY the first int[3] converts to pointer, and then I get (int*)[3] and that is pointer to an array of 3 ints, and not 3 pointers to 3 different arrays?

Comment: Yes. But the pointer still points to the same array. That's why you can index it like a real array or increment it to get the next 3 ints E.g. If you have 1D arrat then: `int a[3]; func(a); void func(int *a) {..}`. If you have a 2D array then: `int a[3][3]; func(a); void func(int (*a)[3]) {..}` and so on.

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић I just edited which may add a bit of clarity.

Comment: int (*a)[3] I'm saying that I have array of 3 integers -> int something[3] says that, and by putting (*a) instead of something I'm saying that those 3 integers happen to be pointers? I'm actually saying that those 3 integers have type: pointer. Is that right?

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић No. `int a[3]` is very different from `int (*a)[3]`. In `int (*a)[3]`, `a` is a pointer that points to an array of 3 ints whereas `int a[3]` is an array of 3 ints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99990/discussion-between---and-l3x).

Answer (score 1):

If you want n to vary (and be square), it is best to allocate and use a single dimension array and multiply when you want a different row.

```
int matrix[3*3];
```

How to use it?

```
matrix[row*3+col] = 5;
```

How to pass it.

```
f(int *a,int n)
```

Answer (score 0):

`int**` is a **pointer to a pointer** (pointing on an int).

`int[3][3]`, as a function argument, is converted to a **pointer to an `int` array** - see [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c/1641963#1641963)

So the types don't match, as the compiler is telling you.

Note: if you're doing pointer arithmetic in your function, you can pass `int *a` instead of `int **a` (by casting: `print_matrix((int *)matrix, 3);`. That's ugly but helps to understand what's going on - namely, a `int[3][3]` array is stored in memory **exactly** as a `int[9]` array, and if you're computing the `int` positions yourself, as you do, it will also work as a 1D array.

Comment: `int[3][3]` is an array of arrays. There's no "as a pointer", because it isn't one. It may be a matter of terminology but I think it is important to get this right because it confuses so many beginners (and some non-beginners too)

Comment: As a parameter, int[3][3] is indeed converted to a pointer. But you're right, I'll update the description, it's not quite clear. As it is, I'm mixing the actual  content of the parameters variables with the types that the compiler "sees".

Comment: Yes, I think if you explain that a parameter of type `T[42]` is adjusted to `T*` then it will be clearer. But still, there is no parameter of type `int[N][N]` in the question. There is just an argument.

Comment: @juanchopanza done (NB by parameter I meant function argument)