# Passing address of array

Tags: c

In my main I call this function `add` like this:

```
add(a,b,c,row,col);
```

Its definition is given below:

```
void add(int **a,int **b,int **c,int row,int col)
{

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]*b[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The main function:.......

```
int main()
{
    int c[5][5],i,j;
    int **f; 
    int a[5][5],b[5][5],row,col; 
    printf("Enter row : ");
    scanf("%d",&row); 
    printf("Enter column : ");
    scanf("%d",&col);
    printf("Enter matrix A :\n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Enter matrix B :\n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
        }
    }


    add(a,b,c,row,col);  

    printf("Addition :\n");

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The errors given by compilers:

```
||warning: command line option '-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\Amir Khasru\Desktop\matrix_add.c|5|warning: no previous declaration for 'add' [-Wmissing-declarations]|
C:\Users\Amir Khasru\Desktop\matrix_add.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\Amir Khasru\Desktop\matrix_add.c|45|error: passing argument 1 of 'add' from incompatible pointer type|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: ok, so what's the question?

Comment: What's the problem with the declaration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function

Comment: `int **` and `int [][]` are incompatible data types.  Instead of `int **`, you need to use `int (*)[]` with the appropriate value for the array dimension (in this case, it's 5).  So `int (*a)[5]`.  If you want to allow a variable dimension, then you can pass that as an argument that precedes the array argument.

Comment: What happened to `#include <stdio.h>` A fragmented [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is one card short of a full house.

Comment: @MichaelPetch lovely to see you on a C thread. Is the wind from the Northbridge today?

Comment: @WeatherVane : lol, it is a slow day on the assembler related tags. Was bored of editing questions lol.

Comment: @MichaelPetch so... I should have said "Southbridge" perhaps. Sorry I deleted the earlier comment.

Answer (score 3):

When passed, `a`, `b` and `c` decay to `int (*)[5]`, rather than `int **`.

So you should rewrite your function as:

```
void add(int a[][5], int b[][5], int c[][5], size_t row, size_t col)
{
    size_t i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] * b[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The confusion is in the fact that `int x[5]` is not a pointer. It can be used as a pointer, but it is actually a block of 5 `int`s. And by this logic, `int y[5][5]` is also not a double pointer. This however cannot be used as a double pointer. Simply because there is no actual pointer pointing to each row. It is just a bunch (25) of integers, of which you( and the compiler) know how big each row is. So that you know that element [0,4] are the first row [5,9] the second, etc.
This means that you have to tell the function how log the rows are. There are two ways to do this. One is to explicitly make add accept blocks of 5x5

```
void add(int a[5][5],int b[5][5],int c[5][5],int row,int col){
   ...
}
```

The other is to pass it as a single pointer (eg. `int* a`), and to pass the width as another argument.

Answer (score 1):

In your add function, `int**` is NOT `int[][]`
Both are extremely different datatypes, one is an array of arrays, and the other is a pointer to a pointer. You should declare it as a `int (*name)[size]`
or alternatively (this happens to be my favorite way), typecast it to a pointer and then use simple pointer arithmetic -

```
int add(int *a, int *b, int *c, int rows, int columns, int rowsize){
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            *(c + rowsize*i + j) = (*(a + rowsize*i + j))*(*(b + rowsize*i + j));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a nice way, but personally i think the notation `c[ rowsize*i + j]` more clear, but both is good.

Comment: @Davidvanrijn It's a personal preference, since it makes it easy for me to imagine it as a table or cuboid in my head when written like that.

Comment: Yea, whatever works for you :) I just wanted both ways on record. ( I wasn't critisizing)

Comment: @Davidvanrijn I know, I just wanted to explain