# How to send 2D array to a function?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, malloc

I've created a 2D array using this:

```
struct Cars (*ParkingLot)[FloorCount] = malloc(sizeof(struct Cars[FloorCount][10]));
```

I don't know if it matters but the `FloorCount` is set to 1 for now, and `struct Cars` is defined this way:

```
    struct Cars
{
    int ID;
    char color[20];
    char type[20];
};
```

Anyway, I'm trying to use this array in a function, and I can't access the values inside the array.
For example, the next thing:

```
void CarIn (struct Cars *Lot[])
{
   printf("%d", Lot[0][0].ID);
}
ParkingLot[0][0].ID=15;
CarIn(ParkingLot);
```

That's not what I wanna do, but it's the most basic function I can think of using the array, it will help me with the rest.

Edit:
Well, I've managed to print using the function, all I needed is to add `&` before the `Lot[0][0].ID`...
The other problem I have now is that this function doesn't seem to work at all, it always crash:

```
void CarIn (struct Cars *Lot[],struct Cars New)
{
    Lot[0][0]=New;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your sizing is wrong in your allocation declaration for `ParkingLot`. I assume you want 10 cars per floor and an arbitrary number of floors, and if that is the case, then this should be done as:

```
struct Cars (*ParkingLot)[10] = malloc(FloorCount * sizeof *ParkingLot);
```

`ParkingLot` is a pointer to an array of 10 `Cars` (not 10 pointers to `Cars`; rather 10 `Cars` in sequence). `sizeof *ParkingLot` will calculate the memory requirement for holding that many sequential `Cars` structures, and finally, multiplying by `FloorCount` will give you that many floors, of that many cars. For sanity sake you could (and probably should) use the *array allocator* in the standard library, `calloc`, though it isn't strictly needed. It would look something like this:

```
struct Cars (*ParkingLot)[10] = calloc(FloorCount, sizeof *ParkingLot);
```

Some find it clearer, and relish in the fact it zero-initializes the allocated memory.

---

On to your question, to pass a true array of arrays (as opposed to an array of pointers) your function parameter declaration is incorrect.

This:

```
void CarIn (struct Cars *Lot[])
```

declares an arbitrary-length array of `struct Cars *`, and indeed the above is equivalent to this:

```
void CarIn (struct Cars **Lot)
```

You want *neither* of those if your intent is to pass a true array of arrays (which is what your allocation is indeed acquiring). Instead, you want something like this:

```
void CarIn (struct Cars Lot[][10])
```

or equivalently, this:

```
void CarIn (struct Cars (*Lot)[10])
```

To pass a  true array of arrays to a function, *all* dimensions but the most-superior must be provided in the declaration. The above declare an arbitrary length array of element-count-10 arrays of `Cars`.

Note: This *can* be done with variable-length syntax as well, if the sizing for the array of arrays inferior dimension is runtime-generated, but that doesn't seem to be your question (yet). For now, the above should get you where you want to go.

Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

`struct` does not create a 2D array, `struct` creates a structure - a *'template'* that unifies different data types and stores them as an 'unity' in memory

A 2D array is created by i.e. `int 2Darray[3][4] = {{0,1,2},{8,9,10,11}};`

A 2D array of a structure is created by i.e. `struct Cars cars2Darray[10][10];`

See this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

To pass a 2D array to a function as argument one possible method is to use a pointer to the 0-element of the array i.e. *2D_array[0]* (if the array is named *2D_array*).

In the following the pointer *'ptr'* points to the 0-element of the int-array *'1D_array'*

```
int 1D_array[8]= { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };
int *ptr; 
ptr = 1D_array;
```

The `ptr = 1D_array` stores the address of the 0th element of *1D_array* in *ptr*, so *ptr* now points to the 0-th element of *1D_array*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
   int 1D_array[8]= { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };
   int *ptr;
   int i;

   ptr = 1D_array;
   printf("The value, *ptr points to, is %d\n", *ptr);
   printf("When applying *ptr+1 it points to %d\n", *(ptr+1));
   printf("*(ptr+3) = %d\n", *(ptr+3));
   printf("\n all elements of 1D_array : \n");
   for(i=0; i<8; i++)
      printf("element[%d]=%d \n", i, *(ptr+i));
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As `ptr` now points to the 0th element of *1D_array* you can use it to pass the array to a function.

**For how to pass a 2D array to a function there are 3 methods (2 using pointers) see this** **[Correct way of passing 2 dimensional array into a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function)**

Comment: As you can see, I need to create a 2D array of structs, and since I'm using `malloc` in order to create it, I have a pointer to that array already.
I already managed to print using the function, all I needed is to add `&` 
But now I have another problem..

Comment: i did not get that this is a **dynamic** method of memory allocation to create array `struct Cars (*ParkingLot)[10] = malloc(FloorCount * sizeof *ParkingLot);`