# Two linked .c files with a .h file, cannot pass reference to global double[][]

Tags: c, linker, segmentation-fault, linker-errors

there are a lot of explanations about these things, but I cannot seem to get the basic concepts with variables between .h and .c files. I cannot change the layout, so to speak, of the files and their contents. Here is my code:

driver.h

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H

//size limits for Pk
double limit_x;
double limit_y;
double limit_z;

//grid cells
int cells_x = 500;
int cells_y = 500;
int cells_z = 500;

extern double particles[][3];

extern double randMtoN();
extern int populateParticles();

#endif
```

driver.c

```
#include "driver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>   

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    //seed rand()
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    //add particles to box 
    limit_x = 200;
    limit_y = 200;
    limit_z = 200;
    int particle_no = 10000;

    double particles[particle_no][3];

    //memset(particles, 0, sizeof particles);

    populateParticles(limit_x, limit_y, limit_z, particle_no, particles);
    printf("l\n");

    printf("%d %f %f %f", 1, particles[0][0], particles[0][1], particles[0][2]);         
}
```

functions.c:

```
 double randMtoN(double M, double N) {
    return M + (rand() * N);
}


int populateParticles(double limit_x, double limit_y, double limit_z, int particle_no, double **particles) {

    //double particles[particle_no][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < particle_no; i++) {

        particles[i][0] = randMtoN(0, limit_x);
        particles[i][1] = randMtoN(0, limit_y);
        particles[i][2] = randMtoN(0, limit_z);     

    }

    return 0;

}
```

What I get is this warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rand’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  return M + (rand() * N);

And then a segfault (due to the particles[][] in functions.c)

Comment: 2D arrays are not double pointers.  Also, if `functions.c` uses `rand()`, it needs to `#include <stdlib.h>`.  And if `driver.h` is included in separate translation units, they'll each get independent copies of the global vars -- consider `extern`.

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite it without the separate include in functions.c? To just have a bare function that has all access to what driver.c has?

Comment: Actually, in the code you've shown, none of the global vars in `driver.h` are actually used, except `limit_x` etc. which could just as easily be local to `main()` or replaced by literals.

Comment: If `driver.c` needs declarations from a header file, it'll have to `#include` it... you can't really get around that.  But why would that be a problem?  Also, your crash probably comes from passing the 2D array of `double` (`particles` from `main()`) to a function treating it as `double **`, which is not equivalent.

Comment: How do I correctly pass this array(or reference to it) such that I can modify it from functions.c as a global variable?

Comment: If the inner array dimension is always 3, just pass it as `double particles[][3]` instead of `double **particles`

Comment: Nope, still a segfault

Comment: Do not (I.E. NEVER) place variable declarations (instance of the variable) in a header (*.h) file.  Instead, place the variable declarations in a source (*.c) file.  That way there is only one instance of the variable.  Then the header file (*.h) file, to make the variables visible in other files, should contain the appropriate `extern` statements for those variables.  In some linkers and depending on the options used, placing a variable declaration in a header file will result in multiple instances of that variable, which is (usually) not what is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

you have two incarnations of the `limit_x` etc variables. You'd have to *declare* all your variables with `extern` and without the initialization in the `.h` file. Then you'd have to pick one of your `.c` files and *define* and initialize the variables, there.

Comment: what about the cells_x etc. are they the correct type, or is there a better way to have them defined in driver.h?

Comment: No, `.h` should only have declarations. Definitions are for `.c` files.

Comment: Thank you! Will fix that

Answer (score 1):

In functions.c you have not included `stdlib.h` which contains the definition of `rand()`.

Comment: Shouldn't it get this automatically as it's linked to driver.c by running

gcc -o driver_data.out driver.c functions.c

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the two other answers:

> And then a segfault (due to the particles[][] in functions.c)

In the file `functions.c`, your definition:

```
int populateParticles(double limit_x, double limit_y, double limit_z, int particle_no, double **particles) {…}
```

resulting in compiler warning:

```
incompatible pointer types passing 'double [particle_no][3]' to parameter of
  type 'double **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

and the `Segmentation fault` execution error,

should be changed into:

```
int populateParticles(double limit_x, double limit_y, double limit_z, int particle_no, double particles[][3]) {…}
```

resulting in the expected behavior.

> ...cannot pass reference to global double[][]

**NB**: There is no "passing reference" in **C**. For further reading, please see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function).

Comment: Still get a segfault, why can't I edit values of this array dynamically in my functions.c file?

Comment: This is tested and working, else I wouldn't have posted. You might have not read the answers carefully and corrected your code. These three answer include all you need to fix your code to work.