# Passing array in as parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to write a function that manipulates an array directly.I don't want to return anything, so obviously I'm going to be using pointers in some fashion.

```
void makeGraph(some parameter) {
    //manipulates array
}

int main() {
    char graph[40][60];
    makeGraph(????)

}
```

I can't figure out what to pass in as parameters. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can pass the array directly: `void makeGraph(char graph[][60]) {` note that you don't need to specify the first dimension, call it using `makeGraph(graph)`

Comment: Are dimensions fixed at compile time (so you can for example use *#define* for them)?

Comment: Yeah they're fixed. I do a #define and then some computation with them.

Comment: @keineLust why do I need to specify the size? And why don't I need to specify the size of the first array?

Comment: `void makeGraph(int rows, int cols, char graph[rows][cols])`, `makeGraph(40, 60, graph)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C array can be passed as a pointer to its first element. The function prototype could be any of these

```
void makeGraph(char graph[40][60]);
void makeGraph(char graph[][60]);
void makeGraph(char (*graph)[60]);
```

To call this function you can pass argument as

```
makeGraph(graph);  //or
makeGraph(&graph[0]);
```

Comment: Ok got it. Why is it that C knows the first array?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: Oh sorry! Why is it that you don't have to specify the size of the first array?

Comment: @namarino; In case of 2D array, compiler just need size of second dimension for pointer arithmetic. First dimension can be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to write a function that manipulates an array directly.I don't want to return anything, so obviously I'm going to be using pointers in some fashion.

In **C** when you pass `array` automatically the base address of the array is stored by the *formal parameter* of the called function(here, `makeGraph()`) so any changes done to the formal parameter also effects the *actual parameter* of the calling function(in your case `main()`).

So you can do this way:

```
void makeGraph(char graph[][60])
{
    //body of the function...
}

int main(void)
{
     //in main you can call it this way:
     char graph[40][60];
     makeGraph(graph)
}
```

There are even other ways you can pass an array in *C*. Have a look at this post: [Correct way of passing 2 dimensional array into a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function)

Answer (score 2):

```
void makeGraph(char graph[40][60]                 
{  // access array elements as graph[x][y] x and y are any number with in the array size 
 }

 int main(void) 
{ //in main you can call it this way: 
 char graph[40][60];  

 makeGraph(graph) 

}
```