# 2D array as pthread function argument

Tags: c, arrays, pthreads

I am trying to pass a 2d array into a pthread function, but I can not find a way to get access to the array content during pthread process, how can I do it?
I tried

```
int ** array = (int **)arg;
```

but it caused segfault after I tried to change the stored value;
Here is part of my code:

```
int message1[2][64];
int i = 0;
for (; i < 2; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < 64; j++)
    {
        message[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
pthread_t tid[1];
pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, xD, message);
```

the function:

```
void * xD(void * arg)
{
     int ** array = (int **)arg;
     array[0][0] = 2;
}
```

Comment: `int **` is not a 2D array.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala so how can I change this line so that I can get access to the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't find a proper duplicate for this. `int **` is not a 2D array but a pointer to a pointer to an int.

What you want to pass in [is a pointer to an array[64] of `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function), i.e. `int (*array)[64]`.

Try

```
int (*array)[64] = arg;
```

Comment: some "array/pointers FAQ" desperately needed ;) Maybe I'll write one some day ... anyways, good answer, to the point in this case!