# Any easy way to create a byte array for a font of variable height?

Tags: c, arduino, processing

I'm doing a project that requires me to write a little library with some definitions like the following for each character in my alphabet.

```
byte _A[5] = {
0b00000001,
0b11101110,
0b11101110,
0b11101110,
0b00000001 };
```

My "font" is going to be 16 pixels tall by let's say 6 wide. Is there any way to generate this already, like some sweet web app, so that I don't have to do it manually/write my own app to do it?

Comment: [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6870002/733077) shows one way to do it: arithmetic and enums.

Answer (score -1):

I created a light web app that accomplishes this for me. I have it on GitHub @ https://github.com/prismspecs/uint-text-creator and also simply online and ready to use @ http://graysonearle.com/test/16_t.html
Hope someone gets use out of it.