# Is array copied if given as an argument to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm curious if I give an n-dimensional array for n>1 as an argument to a function, are the contents of whole array copied or just the pointer to the address of the first element.

Assume function signature is something like this:

```
int someFunction(int n, int arr[n][n]);
```

Comment: This is something that you could (a) easily try out and (b) do a little web searching for (e.g. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/).

Comment: What do you mean by "array copied?"  Nothing is copied on a function call.  Just a pointer being passed in.

Comment: @LeorA - think again (what if an `struct` is passed)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:  C doesn't have multidimensional arrays as part of the langauge.  It has arrays of arrays (and arrays of pointers to arrays) neither of which is quite a proper multidimensional array, though either can be used as such in some contexts.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: How would you distinguish "multidimensional array" from "array of arrays"?  (Also note that the phrase "multidimensional array" is indeed used in the language standard...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: A proper multidimensional array would support things like transposing dimensions and slicing.  C does not.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I'm not sure that's intrinsic to the definition; that's just functionality.  It doesn't have slicing for 1D arrays either...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You can extract a slice from a 1D array with pointer addition.  But yes, C arrays aren't really fully arrays either, as they magically turn into pointers in many contexts, leading to confusion for new programmers

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Well, that's essentially true for 2D arrays too (it's just a little more complicated ;) ).  Anyway, I fear we may be straying from the question topic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*[Where I just re-learned this yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6862954/733077)*]

This is a C99 extension that is not widely known. The array is still passed *by reference* as they always have been, but the compiler is able to interpret it as an array similar to the way it handles Variable-Length Arrays.

This won't give you bound-checking, of course. C doesn't have that.

In your function signature,

```
int someFunction(int n, int arr[n][n]);
```

The final `n` doesn't really buy you anything, it just gets ignored. But `int arr[n][]` is *new*. That's what C89 didn't have. Previously, the only option was to calculate indices manually off of the base pointer, `arr[n*x+y]`.

In Ansi-C (C89), you'd have to declare the function as,

```
int someFunction(int n, int arr[]);
```

which is equivalent to

```
int someFunction(int n, int *arr);
```

and calculate the two dimensions as a single index.

The new C99 magic, reduces the original to this:

```
int someFunction(int n, int *arr[n]);
```

I'd describe the process more as array *adoption*, than passing. It just mitigates some of the losses that were incurred by the original decision to pass arrays as pointers.

---

It's important to understand that second two examples are sort-of *internalized* equivalents. Figurative illustrations. In the final one, the array is *not* converted into an array of pointers, but the bounds of the lowest dimension is dropped. Perhaps it's better illustrated like this:

```
int someFunction(int n, int arr[n][]);
```

---

The only way to *copy* an array as a function argument is to wrap it in a struct. But then you cannot have variable dimensions.

```
struct arr {int n; int arr[n][n];}; //Nope, won't compile!

enum { n = 3 };
struct arr { int arr[n][n]; };

struct arr someFunction( struct arr ); //argument and return value are copied.
```

And this has been legal since 1989.

Comment: Thanks, details in different versions of C are always confusing :)

Comment: `int someFunction(int n, int arr[][]);` is invalid C. And an array of pointers as you have in your last examples is different from a multidimensional array.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got confused by reading too much on tuhs.org. There are primitive versions which *do* accept that syntax.

Answer (score -1):

That's an illegal signature for a function, as arrays in function signatures must have constant dimensions (other than the final dimension).

The *reason* that arrays must have constant sizes as function parameters is because they aren't actually copied in the function call -- only a pointer is passed.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree… but GCC and Clang will both happily compile a function with that signature!

Comment: This is valid in C99, I believe... (see the examples in section 6.7.5.3)

Comment: Besides this answer being based on a false premise, I also don't see why you think that an array having a constant size has anything to do with whether it is copied or not.

Comment: It is correct per C89, and covers the rationale behind not allowing unspecified sizes on array dimensions other than the last one.