# How to pass a 2d array as an argument to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I initialized a 2D int array in my main function with `int weight[numComponents][numSchemes];`

Now I would like to pass it on to a function to add items to it.

I was wondering what the correct way to do this is. 
I came across this answer [C -- passing a 2d array as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862813/c-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-function-argument)

But it seems like the array gets initialized in the function itself instead of beforehand. 
If anyone could help, that would be great. Just looking to be able to pull some statements like 
`weight[0][0] = 50;`

 `weight[0][3] = 20;`

Comment: you can also pass an initialised array ;)

Comment: What would be the correct way to do it? `void weightInput(int array[][])`

Comment: pretty much as in accepted answer in the link you posted .

Comment: This is just an *example* of what you can do inside a function. Where is your problem? What did you try?

Comment: if `numComponents` and `numSchemes` are global variables then yes , other wise you should pass them as well

Answer (score 1):

A simple example for passing a 2D array as a function argument:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void weightInput(int numComponents, int numSchemes, int weight[][numSchemes])
{
    weight[0][0] = 50;
    weight[0][3] = 20;
}
int main() 
{
    int numComponents = 3, numSchemes = 4;
    int weight[numComponents][numSchemes];
    weightInput(numComponents, numSchemes, weight);
    printf("%d\n", weight[0][0]);
    printf("%d\n", weight[0][3]);
}
```