# two dimensional array C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, matrix

I have a code:

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      double A[600][4],  b[600], c[4] ;
      j = rand_lp(600, &(A[0][0]), &(b[0]), &(c[0]), &(result[0]));
    }
    int rand_lp(int n, double *A, double *b, double *c, double *result)
    {
      permutation(n, A, b);
      return 0;
    }
    void permutation(int n, double *A, double *b)
    {
      int i;
      int k;
      double tmp0, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmpb;

      for(i = n; i > 0; i--)
      {
          k = rand()%i;

          tmp0 = A[i][0]; // error : subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
          tmp1 = A[i][1];
        tmp2 = A[i][2];
        tmp3 = A[i][3];
        tmpb = b[i];

        A[i][0] = A[k][0];
        A[i][1] = A[k][1];
        A[i][2] = A[k][2];
        A[i][3] = A[k][3];
        b[i] = b[k];

        A[k][0] = tmp0;
        A[k][1] = tmp1;
        A[k][2] = tmp2;
        A[k][3] = tmp3;
        b[k] = tmpb;
      }
   }
```

So de facto I need to shuffle a matrix, that's why I need access to all coefficents, by C doesn't suppot 2-dem arrays I read. 
I can't change the call and the arguments of the function "rand_lp".
Any ideas?

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* because you use the arrays without initialization.

Comment: As for your problem, an array of `double` (like `b` or `c`) naturally decays to a pointer to `double`, but an array of arrays of `double` doesn't decay to that, it decays to a a pointer to arrays of `double`, i.e. `double (*a)[]`.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize what to do to solve this problem

Comment: "C doesn't suppot 2-dem arrays I read." This is incorrect. `int a[10][10];` is a 2 dimensional array and totally legal in C.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862813/c-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-function-argument

Comment: I can't change the call and the arguments of the function "rand_lp"

Comment: if the dimensions of the array are always the same, you could change the parameters of permutation.

Comment: @user2970104 in your function *definition*, `void permutation(int n, double *A, double *b)`, `double *A` should be `double (*A)[4]` or `double A[][4]` (both are equivalent, your choice). The change should be made in each function *declaration/definition* passing `A`. Note, when you call the functions in your code for use, you simply pass `A`, ( e.g. `permutation (n, A, b)`)

Comment: you can also use `double **A` if your array is done in the right way or encode N-dimensions to 1D array ...