# C - how to pass a variable 2d array as parameter

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to pass a 2D array as a parameter. The issue is that the size of the 2d array always varies. So I can't write something like myfunction(int a[2][5]);

I have a header file containing a lot of 3D-coordinates.
e.g.:

```
float someArray[][3] = {{0.0,1.0,-2.0},{-1.0,1.0,-2.0},{-1.0,1.0,0.0},{0.0,1.0,0.0},
            {-1.0,0.75,-2.0},{-1.0,1.0,-2.0},{-1.0,1.0,0.0},{-1.0,0.75,0.0},
            {0.0,0.75,-2.0},{0.0,1.0,-2.0},{0.0,1.0,0.0},{0.0,0.75,0.0}, 
            {0.0,0.75,-2.0},{-1.0,0.75,-2.0},{-1.0,0.75,0.0},{0.0,0.75,0.0},
            {0.0,0.75,-2.0},{-1.0,0.75,-2.0},{-1.0,1.0,-2.0},{0.0,1.0,-2.0},
            }; 


void drawVertex(const float **vertex, int numberVertex, int shape)
{
    int i;

    glPushMatrix();
    switch(shape)
    {
        case 0: glBegin(GL_LINES); break;
        case 1: glBegin(GL_POLYGON); break;
        default: break;
    }

    for(i=0;i<numberVertex;i++)
    {
        glVertex3fv(vertex[i]);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

}
```

the function calls I tried:

these just crash (core dump)

```
drawVertex(someArray, 6,1);
drawVertex(*someArray, 6,1);
```

Should I modify the parameters of the function drawVertex() ? I've tried many things but nothing seems work.

Comment: `const GLfloat **` is not a 2D array and cannot represent one. Use normal array notation or an explicit pointer to array (due do automatic conversion of format parameters they are identical).

Comment: And after carrying out @Olaf's suggestion, can't you make it global?

Comment: Compiler warnings are not just to show some fancy messages. Don't ignore them and you are expected to have them enabled and payed heed to them before asking.

Comment: @abhishek_naik: You hopefully mean "**can** you make it **not** global?" Anyway, as that is an initialised `const` qualified array, making it global is well acceptable. It just should have internal linkage, i.e. `static`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C -- passing a 2d array as a function argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862813/c-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-function-argument)

Comment: @Olaf, however this solution gives this warning: warning: 

passing argument 1 of ‘drawVertex’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  drawVertex(myShape,6,0);
  ^
mijnTest.c:21:6: note: expected ‘const GLfloat (*)[3]’ but argument is of type ‘GLfloat (*)[3]’
 void drawVertex(const GLfloat vertex[][3], int numberVertex, int shape)
      ^

Comment: @privetDruzia You might have to drop the const correctness. C is a bit dumb when it comes to mixing const with arrays decaying into array pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an array, you must use an array. Pointer-to-pointers have little to do with arrays. Change the function to:

```
void drawVertex(const GLfloat vertex[][3], int numberVertex, int shape)
```

or better yet:

```
void drawVertex(int numberVertex, const GLfloat vertex[numberVertex][3] int shape)
```

Comment: I really like the second option you proposed, nice one. However the compiler says "numberVertex undefined". The issue is this I can't use #define because it is a variable that will change every time I call that function

Comment: @privetDruzia: If you get such an error, you have a typo. Anyway, as the outermost dimension is not used anyway, there is no need to specify it. It is good for documentation purposes, though.

Comment: @privetDruzia You might have a 26 years old compiler. Consider upgrading to one which is not older than 17 years.

Comment: @Olaf, Ok I ll accept that answer. Didn't see the link you posted above. shall I delete this question? (to avoid being downvoted for duplication continuously...)

Comment: @Lundin, what makes you think my compiler is that old?

Comment: @privetDruzia I posted no link, someone else did. If your post is a duplicate, it will get closed. I'm not so sure I agree that it is a duplicate of the linked question though.

Comment: @privetDruzia Because it seems it follows the C standard from 1990 rather than the one from 1999 or later, where variable-length arrays were introduced.

Comment: @privetDruzia: Please add the compiler+version+how you call it to your question text. Ubuntu LTS still uses gcc 4.8 which defaults to gnu90 (C90+extensions).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the input here is a pointer to a pointer `const float **vertex`, which I don't really understand.  Can you define as `void drawVertex(const float vertex[][3], int numberVertex, int shape)`?  Also, it looks like you are trying to input an array of constant values; however, the input `someArray[][3]` is not defined as an array of constants.