# incompatible pointer type in making 2D array struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to make 2D array struct in C like this in main function.

```
function_1(struct example** ex){}
void main(){
    struct example ex[num_1][num_2];
    function(ex);
}
```

But gcc keep telling me that type of ex and struct example** ex is different.
How can I solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C -- passing a 2d array as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862813/c-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-function-argument)

Comment: @RetiredNinja Unfortunately, It doesn't

Comment: When an "array of T" is passed to a function, it is converted to "pointer to T". In your case, what you pass to the function is "array with num_1 elements of array with num_2 elements of example". This is converted to "pointer to array of num_2 elements of example" and passed to the function. However, your function expects "pointer to pointer to example".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my original answer:

You could instead write

```
function_1(struct example (*pex) [num_1][num_2]){}
void main(){
    struct example ex[num_1][num_2];
    function(& ex);
}
```

at least if you know `num_1` and `num_2` at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array expression doesn’t decay to a pointer to pointer, it decays to a pointer to an *array*.

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the call to `function`, the expression `ex` decays from type "`num_1`-element array of `num_2`-element array of `struct example`" to "pointer to `num_2`-element array of `struct example`", so your function prototype needs to be

```
void function( struct example (*ex)[num_2] )
{
  ...
  ex[i][j] = some_value();
  ...
}
```

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are "adjusted" to `T *a`, so you could also write that prototype as

```
void function( struct example ex[][num_2] )
{
  ...
  ex[i][j] = some_value();
  ...
}
```

There are a couple of problems with this - `function` doesn’t know how many rows are in the array, so you would need to pass that as a separate parameter:

```
void function( struct example (*ex)[num_2], size_t rows )
{
  ...
}
```

Also the function can only accept arrays with `num_2` columns - it cannot work on any arbitrarily-sized 2D array.

If your function needs to handle arbitrarily-sized arrays and you have a compiler that supports variable-length arrays, you can do something like this:

```
void function( size_t rows, size_t cols, struct example ex[rows][cols] )
{
  ...
}
```

and call it from `main` as

```
function( num_1, num_2, ex );
```

If your compiler doesn’t support VLAs, you’ll have to get creative.  One trick is to pass a pointer to the first element and treat it as a 1D array in the function:

```
void function( struct example *ex, size_t rows, size_t cols )
{
  ...
  ex[i * rows + j] = some_value();
  ...
}
```

and call it as

```
function( &ex[0][0], num_1, num_2 );
```

Note that this trick only works for 2D arrays defined as

```
T a[M][N];
```

or arrays dynamically allocated as

```
T (*p)[N] = malloc( sizeof *p, M );
```

It won’t work for 2D arrays allocated as

```
T **p = malloc( sizeof *p * M );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  p[i] = malloc( sizeof *p[i], N );
```

but in that case, your function prototype would be

```
void function( T **p, size_t rows, size_t cols )
{
  ...
}
```

As a final note, `main` returns `int`, not `void`.  Older compilers won’t complain, but the behavior is undefined and could cause problems at runtime.