# Incompatible pointer type array to pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a problem with pointer types. GCC compiler throws a warning like this:

```
416:31: warning: passing argument 1 of 'locateInHWNDArray' from 
    incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         locateInHWNDArray(hWndLWTxt, (HWND)lParam, &x, &y);
                           ^
foodplaner.c:76:6: note: expected 'struct HWND__ ***'
but argument is of type 'struct HWND__ * (*)[4]'
void locateInHWNDArray(HWND **array, HWND el, int *x, int *y);
     ^
```

The function signature looks like this:

```
void locateInHWNDArray(HWND **array, HWND el, int *x, int *y)
```

and the call is the following

```
locateInHWNDArray(hWndTWTxt, (HWND)lParam, &x, &y);
```

with hWndTwTxt declared as

```
HWND hWndTWTxt[7][4];
```

I assume this has to do something with having it declared with a certain size, but I have no idea what the compiler exactly wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a two-dimensional array and a pointer to a pointer are not the same thing.

> foodplaner.c:76:6: note: expected 'struct HWND__ ***'
>   but argument is of type 'struct HWND__ * (*)[4]'

The first part of this error message (before the "but") simply means that `HWND` is equivalent to a `HWND__ *`  (where `HWND__` is a type defined in a header file included in your project).

The second part of the error message (after the "but") is telling you that `hWndTwTxt` is being passed as a pointer to an array of `4` `HWND__ *`.   This is consistent - a 2D array of dimension `[7][4]` is passed as a pointer to an array of `4` elements.

In combination, the error message is telling you that a 2D array cannot be converted into a pointer to a pointer.

Assuming your function needs to be passed something that resembles a 2D array then you either need specify your function as

```
void locateInHWNDArray(HWND array[7][4], HWND el, int *x, int *y)
```

or as

```
void locateInHWNDArray(HWND (*array)[4], HWND el, int *x, int *y)
```

Either of these rely on the second (right-most) dimension (i.e. `4`) being known at compile time.   Either way, the function must use valid array indices  (i.e.  when doing something with `array[i][j]`, `i` must be between `0` and `7` and `j` must be between `0` and `4`).

If you really want to pass a `HWND **` (i.e. not changing the function argument types) then you will need to do something like this

```
HWND **temp;
int i, j;
temp = malloc(7*sizeof(*temp));
for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
{
    temp[i] = malloc(4*sizeof(*temp[i]));
    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        temp[i][j] = hWndTWText[i][j];
}

locateInHWNDArray(temp, (HWND)lParam, &x, &y);

/* copy from temp back to `hWndTWText` if the function modifies elements */

for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    free(temp[i]);
free(temp);
```

The function still needs to ensure indices are valid (which, if the array dimension are not fixed at compile time, means they must be passed, somehow, to the function - for example, as additional arguments).

Answer (score 2):

HWND **array expects an array of pointers, not a 2D array. You can declare it as:

```
HWND* hWndTWTxt[n]
```

You must then create each pointer in the array individually.

See this answer for more explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16724679/6726446

Answer (score 0):

[Here is what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11428548/6180573).

In short, you need to pass the number of dimensions as pointers, but since you have a static array (and a static 2D array requires that second level of pointers be `const` pointer to static array), this will work:

```
void locateInHWNDArray(HWND array[7][4], HWND el, int *x, int *y)
```

Or use any of the ways listed in the linked answer.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? With this version I got no compile errors/warnings.

Comment: @DQQpy Heh, no idea. The important thing is that it works for you!