# a parameter is not allowed error

Tags: c, signal-processing, texas-instruments

I am trying to run a code on DSP TMS320C6472 architecture using Code Composer studio. However,  I get this error

> ```
> a parameter is not allowed
> ```

which points to

```
 void affichage(int ligne,int col,double A[ligne][col])
```

Meanwhile, I don't get this error with ARM cortex-M0 architecture.

I tried to modify `A[ligne][col]` from a matrix to an array but I got the same error.

So does anyone have a clue what is the problem here? 
Also my colleague said that a matrix is not allowed with DSP, is that right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a matrix in a function (C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428526/passing-a-matrix-in-a-function-c)

Comment: [This might require C99](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6862954/597607) which not all compilers use, or not use by default.

Comment: Bo Persson mght be correct there, I have used CCS with TI's C2000 series uC's for which the compiler uses C89 with some C90 and C99 bits and pieces by default. You should be able to check what standard the compiler is building to using the project's properties. There should be information on this either way in the C6x C/C++ compiler tools documentation