# How do I make a function that takes a 2d matrix as a parameter (and modifies it) in C?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing, transpose

I am trying to make a function to calculate the transpose of a matrix of ints. The function takes the two dimensions of the matrix, those being d1 and d2, and the matrix itself, named arr, as well a a matrix called dest, which will be the transpose. Here's the code that I am trying to use:

```c
void transpose(size_t d1, size_t d2, int arr[d1][d2], int dest[d2][d1])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d1; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < d2; j++)
        {
            dest[j][i] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

And here is what I get when I try to compile:

```
Exercicios\source\9.52.c:5:48: error: use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
 void transpose(size_t d1, size_t d2, int arr[d1][d2], int dest[d2][d1])
                                                ^
Exercicios\source\9.52.c:5:52: error: use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
 void transpose(size_t d1, size_t d2, int arr[d1][d2], int dest[d2][d1])
                                                    ^
Exercicios\source\9.52.c:5:53: error: expected ')' before ',' token
 void transpose(size_t d1, size_t d2, int arr[d1][d2], int dest[d2][d1])
               ~                                     ^
                                                     )
Exercicios\source\9.52.c:5:55: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
 void transpose(size_t d1, size_t d2, int arr[d1][d2], int dest[d2][d1])
```

Seeing this, one would probably say that I simply can't use the value of an argument in another argument, and it is what I thought the same, however, this function seems to work an [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) and using the arguments as dimensions for other arguments was suggested on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428526/passing-a-matrix-in-a-function-c), as well as some articles here and there, so it must be (sort of) right.
Even then, it does not work on my compiler(mingw-w64), so I was hoping anybody could help me figure this out.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I know that the Visual Studio (MSVC) `C` compiler will reject your code (it uses a very old `C`-language standard)  but `clang` compiles your code, no problem. But I'm not sure what the minimum `C`-standard you need for such variable-length array arguments. Others here will know, though!

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica VLA support is mandatory in C99 and optional in C11.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the clarification! So it seems that it came in 1999 and went away again in 2011? But, IIRC, MSVC *still* uses C90!!

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica VLAs didn't technically go away in C11. They just became optional. Many compilers like gcc support it even for C11 mode.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica I am using the latest release of mingw-w64, it it possible to do what I want in this compiler or do I need to use another one?

Comment: Not sure - but other will be. However, if you're using a `c++` compiler, your code will fail *whatever* language standard you use (unless you have something with a *very* non-standard extension).

Comment: By mingw-w64, you mean GCC, do you? Try to add `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` to command line you use to compile your program.