# Passing a 2D pointer array to a function with a 1D pointer array parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am currently doing a project where I am going to pass a 2D pointer array to a function. Here is the function implementation:

```
void
affiche_Tab2D(int *ptr, int n, int m)
{
    if (n>0 && m>0 && ptr!=NULL)
    {
        int (*lignePtr)[m]; // <-- Its my first time to see this declaration

        lignePtr = (int (*)[m]) ptr; // <-- and this too....

        for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < m ; j++) 
            {
                printf("%5d ",lignePtr[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\b\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that ptr is 2D array but it uses a single pointer. Before, I used to pass 2D array using double pointers. In my main I have set up a 2D array (double pointer) and finding ways how to send it to that function.

Here are the function calls I tried which does not work:

```
int 
main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    int ** numbers_table;
    int i, j;

    numbers_table = (int **)malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        numbers_table[i] = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            numbers_table[i][j] = i + j;

    // Failed function call 1
    // affiche_Tab2D(numbers_table, 10, 10);

    // Failed function call 2
    // affiche_Tab2D(&numbers_table, 10, 10);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    free(numbers_table[i]);

    free(numbers_table);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Show your function call.

Comment: The question is I don't know how to pass my 2D pointer array to the function. I updated the question to show you what I have so far.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546860/passing-arrays-and-matrices-to-functions-as-pointers-and-pointers-to-pointers-in/11274267#11274267

Comment: No this is not a duplicate, take note that I am not allowed to modify the function parameters. The function parameter should stay as is.

Comment: can you try this? : affiche_Tab2D((*numbers_table)[10], 10, 10); im not sure but it should be OK.

Comment: @CagkanToptas I tried, I got a compile time error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' and initializing argument 1 of 'void affiche_Tab2D(int*, int, int)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17569578/183120) shows the various ways of passing 2D arrays to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass `numbers_table` to your function because it is of type `int **` while your function is expecting `int *`. Also you can't pass `&numbers_table` because it is of type `int ***`.
To pass a pointer to `int` to your function pass `&numbers_table[0][0]`, having a type `int *`.

```
affiche_Tab2D(&numbers_table[0][0], 10, 10);
```

---

As per OP's comment:

> I would like to know more about the explanation of the declaration `int (*lignePtr)[m]` and `lignePtr = (int (*)[m]) ptr;` Its a bit confusing to understand.

`int (*lingPtr)[m]` is a pointer to an array (of integers) of `m` elements.
`lignePtr = (int (*)[m]) ptr;` is casting `ptr` to a pointer to array of `m` elements.

Comment: Oh my god, you saved me from hours of head ache. I would like to know more about the explanation of the declaration int (*lignePtr)[m] and
lignePtr = (int (*)[m]) ptr; Its a bit confusing to understand.

Comment: Wait. Updating my answer.

Comment: **Nitpick:** Accessing a 2D array as a 1D array (array flattening) is [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7785116/183120). That said most implementations seem to work fine as they don't do array bounds check.

Comment: @legends2k; Thanks for the link. Never knew that.